Serilog Oracle C# - Remove MessageTemplate column
How to remove MessageTemplate and Properties column in SeriLog Oracle Logger configuration? I am not able to find method to remove it.
Following is the logger configuration I use,
  string connectionString = "User Id=user;Password=pwd;Data Source=dsrc";
  return new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Information()
      .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
           cfg.WithSettings(connectionString, tableSpaceAndTableName: "master_logs")
          .UseBurstBatch()
          .CreateSink()).CreateLogger();

Any suggestion here is greatly appreciated.
